# Find files in multiple directories taken from list in a file?

Tags: grep, find, freebsd

```
FreeBSD 9.2 RELEASE p2
```

I have a file `dirs.txt`. In this file is a new line separated directory list like so:

```
/etc
/home
/home/goods/
```

I need to first find in all directory's files which have names like "good" or contain string "(NODES_'TASK')" and then copy all these files into the directory `/tmp`.

I think must be something like:

```
$ find $fromDirs.txt -type f -name 'good' | \
    grep -lr '\(NODES_\'TASK\'\)' $fromDirs.txt | > /tmp
```

Comment: files with name like good __OR__ containing NODES_TASK ? or files with name like good __AND__ containing NODES_TASK ?

Comment: files with name like good OR containing NODES_TASK, NODES_TASK with specials simbols

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, you have a file containing a list of directories. You want all files that either:

1. are inside a directory in the list where the file content contains `(NODES_'TASK')`
2. are inside a directory in the list where the file name contains `good`.

and then copy these matching files to `/tmp`.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a dirs < fromDirs.txt
find "${dirs[@]}" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "(NODES_'TASK')" {} \; \) -exec cp {} /tmp/ \;
```

This reads `fromDirs.txt` delimited by newline into the array `$dirs`.
The `find` then looks through those directories, if any of the directories in the path contain `good`, or if the file contains `(NODES_'TASK')`, then copy that file into `/tmp`.

*(note: I am using a few bash-specific features here for splitting the file list by newlines)*

Comment: are inside a directory in the list where the **file name** like good. not directory name. /home/goods/good.php, /home/goods/verygood.php, /home/goods/gooddness.php

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin adjusted.

Comment: are inside a directory in the list where the file content contains (NODES_'TASK') **not grep txt file but grep in locations which specified in txt file** take first dir from txt file for example /home/goods/ when grep all files in this directory and subfolders for nodes_task when do the same with another directory from txt file

Comment: fixed a few typos & minor mistakes. Created a test environment, and it works fine now.

Comment: 2.sh: cannot open fromDirs.txt : No such file or directory 
2.sh: ${dirs[...}: Bad substitution
File exist and running from it allocation directory, also i trying to provide full path instead of fromDirs.txt and error the same

Comment: It's meant to be adjusted accordingly. If your file isn't called `fromDirs.txt`, adjust it :-)